# Cannot publish .net6.0 wpf application

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to publish WPF app on .net6.0-windows platform that should be running on Win x64. App is buildable and is running on local, I can publish it in framework-dependant mode, but target PC does not have .Net6.0 so I need self-contained version.

I cannot create self-contained version. It always fails with generic pretty much useless message. [image]

Inside file there is just useless error.

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has
> encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the
> error. Check the output log for more details.     --- End of inner
> exception stack trace ---
> ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has
> encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the
> error. Check the output log for more details. <---
>
> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has
> encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the
> error. Check the output log for more details.
>
> ===================

Only hint I have is build log:

```
1 of 10 projects are up-to-date for restore.
There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'linux-x64'.
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 7 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

But I do not understand what is going on, I am trying to publish app under win x64, not linux.

[image]

App is using .net6.0-windows framework and multiple .net6.0 libraries.

Comment: Have you tried publishing with `dotnet publish ...`?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes. Command dontnet publish --self-contained true -r win-x64 return same error as on last line of build process. There is no runtime pack for Microsoft.WindowsDektop.App.Wpf ... for  linux-x64

Comment: Did you solve this? I ended up in the same exact spot.

Comment: Nope. We had to install Net6 to every tester's PC. It was not fun at all...

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have the correct nuget source, as it tries to pull .net runtime compilers from a nuget source and not from your local machine in order to publish the self-contained solution:
Nuget ORG Public URL: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Add a nuget source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio

Comment: Yea,  it may be correct in some cases. Unfortunately not in mine, so I will not give you accept on this answer just yet. Hopefully someone else will confirm that answer